# Why does TERM variable not reflect True Color support in terminal emulators

Tags: terminal, colors, terminal-emulator

So using the st terminal emulator the `TERM` variable is set to `st-256color`, even `tput colors` gives me 256.

But from multiple sources and the tests I have run, it seems like ST does support TRUECOLOR. See https://github.com/termstandard/colors#fully-supporting

A lot of programs and applications seem to rely on `TERM` or `COLORTERM`(rarely) to detect color support and this seems problematic.

Most information online strongly advise against manually setting `TERM` yourself, so I am not seeing how the issue is resolved?

Is it an issue with ST for not setting the `TERM` variable properly? Is it the application's fault for not checking color capability in a different way?

What is the ideal way to detect true color support in cases such as this?

Answer (score 0):

The `TERM` is not just a variable. It specify which terminal settings should be used. Basically, a terminal understands a lot of escape sequences - but different terminals can do different things for same escape sequence. Or require different escape sequences for the same action. This is solved by database of terminal's escape sequences: `terminfo`.

Go to `/usr/lib/terminfo` (or `/usr/share/terminfo`, that depends on a flavor of *nix) and you will find a lot of files (grouped in directories) - these files the `TERM` actually points to. These are compiled binary files with a list of pairs: control sequence = escape sequence.

You can run `infocmp` to decode the terminfo's file.

Run `man 5 terminfo` for full list and description of control sequences.

If you want to have a True Color on your terminal - find or (write yourself) the corresponding `terminfo` file. After that - you can choose it with the `TERM`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is very helpful. But I just saw that even `kitty` the supposed truecolor terminal (it sets COLORTERM to truecolor) sets max_colors to 0x100 (256) in terminfo. It's not clear what to look for in a truecolor terminal.